# How to run a function that logs an updaing state, every 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a video component in my React project. I receive the current time and the status(paused or playing) of the playing video. And I want to run a function every 2 seconds as long as the video is being played. This function logs an updating state.

When I run the code below, the `logFunction` runs every 2 seconds but it logs the initial state, not the updated state. I also tried adding `currentTime` to the dependencies of the useEffect. But this time it logs every time that `currentTime` changes, not every 2 seconds.

Note: When the video is being played `status` is true, otherwise it's false.

`CourseVide.jsx` :

```
const CourseVideo = () => {
  const { videoDetails } = useVideoPlayer();
  const { currentTime, status } = videoDetails;

    const logFunction = () => {
      console.log('Current Time:', currentTime);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      let intervalId;
      if (status) {
        intervalId = setInterval(logFunction, 2000);
      }
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    }, [status]);


  return (
    <video
        className="video"
        ref={videoRef}
        width="300"
        height="300"
        controls
        controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"
        src={videos[selectedVideo-1].src}
        type="video/mp4"
      />
  );
};

export default CourseVideo;
```